# no possible value in the devtool property of webpack.common.js will generate .map files

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I am using a seed project built by Tynarus, which could be found at the following link:
https://github.com/Tynarus/angular-seed

I have done everything said in previous posts on stackoverflow regarding the devtool property in the webpack.common.js file (webpack.config) but nothing seems to generate .map files for my project.
Things I tried:
1. using **-d** with **webpack**
2. using the values **cheap-module-eval-source-map,module-eval-source-map, cheap-source-map,inline-source-map**
3. I even used

```
new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
  filename: "[file].map"
}),
```

in the plugins array.
4. Tried other suggestions found on the web, but nothing seems to work.

The current state of these configurations are as follows.
**The project structure looks as follows:**
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8XD5.png)

**the tsconfig.js**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
        "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
    ]
},
"include": [
    "../**/*"
]
}
```

**the webpack.common.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const helpers = require('../helpers');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts',
    'styles': './src/global.css'
},
resolve: {
    extensions: [
        '.js', '.ts'
    ]
},

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: [ 'awesome-typescript-loader?configFileName=config/tsconfig.json', 'angular2-template-loader' ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: [ /node_modules/, helpers.root('src', 'global.css') ],
            use: [ 'to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
        },
        {
            test: /global\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                use: 'css-loader!sass-loader'
            })
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|otf|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
            use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
        }
    ],
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: [ 'app', 'vendor', 'polyfills' ]
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
        helpers.root('src'),
        {}
    )
]
};
```

**the webpack.dev.js**

```
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const helpers = require('../helpers');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
devtool: 'source-map',
output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
},

devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'/*,
    TODO setup when REST service ready
    proxy: {
        '/api/**': {
            target: 'http://localhost:8080/your-rest-service',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true
        }
    }*/
},

plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
]
});
```

**The webpack.prod.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const helpers = require('../helpers');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';
module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
devtool: 'source-map',

output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
        mangle: {
            keep_fnames: true
        }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
        }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        options: {
            htmlLoader: {
                minimize: false // workaround for ng2
            }
        }
    })
]
});
```

**The scripts in package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server -d --inline --config config/build/webpack.dev.js --progress --port 3000 --content-base build",
    "test": "karma start config/test/karma.conf.js",
    "coverage": "npm run lint && karma start config/test/karma.conf.js --coverage=true",
    "lint": "tslint -c config/tslint.json \"src/app/**/*.ts\"",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack -d --config config/build/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "server": "node config/server/prod-server.js"
},
```

The dist folder is created with all needed bundle and the seed application runs as expected, including 2 own modules each with its router.
The only problem is that no source.map files are created.
**Versions used :**
**typescript:** ~2.5.2
**webpack:** ~3.4.1
**webpack-dev-server:** ~2.5.1